# Why I should not provide a forward and move versions for my types?

Tags: c++, move, swap, forward

I've used `std::swap`, `std::move` and `std::forward` but I've been recommended not to overload the latter two ones because they already have paramters that can hold any tylpe of value for example a forearding reference. So I should fully-quallify the call to those two functions:

```
std::move(x);
std::forward<T&&>(x);
```

And I've read that I can provide my own version of `swap` and thus I only add a usung declaration for the standard library one then call `swap` without qualifying it (unqualified lookup):

```
using std::swap;// in case my class doesn't provide a swap version

swap(x, y); // where x, y are of class type. so don't use std::swap directly
```

- So why I should not provide a version of `std::move` and `std::forward` for my types too?
- Does this mean if I provided versions, there is no benefit because the library's are better like proving a sort function whereas the library's is so far better?

Comment: What do you think providing an overload of `std::move` would even look like?

Answer (score 3):

You are only allowed to provide specializations of `std` functions when the standard permits you to.  No such permission is given for `std::move` or `std::forward`.  Doing so makes your program ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

`std::swap` you should only specialize (not overload!) when the default implementation has efficiency problems.  The default implementation is a basically:

```
void std::swap( T& lhs, T& rhs ) {
  auto tmp = std::move(lhs);
  lhs = std::move(rhs);
  rhs = std::move(tmp);
}
```

The most common case is when your type needs to allocate memory when it is "empty".  A more efficient swap could avoid such an allocation.

But for most types, this isn't a problem.

Comment: I don't think so for `std::swap` we are overloading it not spectializing it. A specialization of it should look loke: namespace std{ template <> void swap(Foo&, Foo&); // specialization not overload} and if overloding it: void swap(Foo&, Foo&); after all it is a function template so its specialization must be full specializations (template keyword followed with empty brackets <>).

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa User-written overloads in namespace std is never legal.  Your program becomes ill-formed, no diagnostic required.  The standard states when you can add specializations to namespace std, and that such specializations may not break the guaranteed standard requirements, and adding **anything else** is makes your program ill-formed, NDR.  So you must specialize, not accidentally overload.  Of course, an overload sometimes will work with some standard libraries and some uses, which makes it really insidious.